# How do I search an array of objects for any matches containing a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of records with the following pattern:

```
apis = [{
  info: {
    title: 'some title"
  }
}]
```

I need to return all records where the user input is the record's title.

I've tried something like this using Lodash but `"title"` is always a single letter.

```
this.searchResults = this.apis.filter(function(item){
    return _.some(item.info.title, function (title) {
        return _.includes(title, query);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't even need any libraries for that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using ES6 `filter`, you can:

```js
let apis = [
  {info: {title: 'select some title'}},
  {info: {title: 'some title 2'}},
  {info: {title: 'some title 3'}}
];

let toSearch = 'select'; //Will check if title have text 'search'

let result = apis.filter(o => o.info.title.includes(toSearch));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to filter the exact match, you can:

```js
let apis = [
  {info: {title: 'select some title'}},
  {info: {title: 'some title 2'}},
  {info: {title: 'some title 3'}}
];

let toSearch = 'select some title'; 

let result = apis.filter(o=> o.info.title === toSearch);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: How could search by name and lastname if I have this:  apis=[{info: {name:'name1',lastname:'lastname1'}, {info: {name: 'name2', lastname: 'lastname2'}}].  Thanks.

Comment: What an amazing answer! Been looking so long for something like this